P-value changes when invert coding of binary outcome in Poisson GEE with log link but not logistic GEE or OLS
We are running regression models with a binary outcome (Yes/No) on panel data. The outcome is very common (93.6%=Yes, n=3961 of 4231 observations). We are using GEE models to account for the multiple observations per participant.
When we run Poisson GEE models (one model per predictor) with a log link, the p-values differ considerably depending on whether the outcome is positively coded (Yes=1) or negatively coded (No=1), with some results becoming significant depending on the coding. When we run logistic GEE models on the same variables, however, no difference in the p-value is seen based on positive vs. negative coding. (Note: log-binomial models don't converge, so we weren't able to test that).
We have concerns about the validity of the Poisson results if the coding of the outcome can change the significance.
1.) Why would the Poisson models result in different p-values for inverse coding but not logistic? Is it something to do with how common the outcome is (if coded Yes=1)?
2.) Are the results from the Poisson GEEs okay to use provide consistent coding is use (e.g., Yes=1 for all models)?
Example coding for the models:
model1.poisson.yes = geeglm(formula = outcome_yes ~ binary_predictor1, 
              id = uuid,
              family = poisson("log"), 
              corstr = "exchangeable",
              data = df)
 
model1.poisson.no = geeglm(formula = outcome_no ~ binary_predictor1, 
              id = uuid,
              family = poisson("log"), 
              corstr = "exchangeable",
              data = df)

model1.logistic.yes = geeglm(formula = outcome_yes ~ binary_predictor1, 
              id = uuid,
              family = binomial("logit"), 
              corstr = "exchangeable",
              data = df)

model1.logistic.no = geeglm(formula = outcome_no ~ binary_predictor1, 
              id = uuid,
              family = binomial("logit"), 
              corstr = "exchangeable",
              data = df)



Swapping the outcomes is a reflection around 0.5; 1 becomes 0, 0.75 becomes 0.25, etc. The logit is also symmetric around this mean (0 in the link scale), the log is not. You would see the same with a log-binomial model, were it to converge, or with an identity (risk difference) link. The identity parameters would be symmetric around $0.5$, and the log (for very close differences only) around $\text{ln}(0.5)\approx -0.693$.

A Poisson model is designed for count values, making a specific assumption about the association between the mean and the variance of the expected count outcome: the mean equals the variance. As the p-values are based on the variance estimates, and the number of counts (and thus the Poisson variance estimate) differs greatly depending on how you code the outcome, you shouldn't be surprised that different coding leads to different results in a Poisson model. A Poisson model isn't typically appropriate for this type of data, although in practice you might not be too far off if you use counts for the low-probability outcome (coding No = 1 in this case).
A binomial (e.g., logistic) model makes more sense here. The variance of the "success" counts for $n$ trials with probability $p$ of success is $n p (1-p)$, which is symmetric in however you code "success." That's why coding doesn't matter for your logistic regression results.
You'll note that the displayed p-values for your logistic models are close to those for the Poisson models coded with No = 1. That's consistent with the binomial variance in the limit of $p$ close to 0, where the mean (and variance) of counts is close to $np$. Poisson models work best on counts of a low-probability outcome.
A further warning: your "one model per predictor" approach is dangerous in general and particularly so in logistic regression. Even in ordinary least squares regressions, omitting an outcome-associated predictor that is correlated with an included predictor leads to omitted-variable bias. For logistic regression, you get bias even if the omitted predictor is uncorrelated with the others. See this page. Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies explains better ways to build regression models, with substantial attention to logistic regression.

Thanks for the detailed response, and that makes sense re: mean/variance relationship! To clarify - we are using modified (robust) Poisson models as they can provide unbiased estimates of risk ratios for binary outcomes (as discussed for clustered data here: https://academic.oup.com/aje/article-abstract/174/8/984/155441) and are generally more intuitive to interpret compared to ORs from logistic regression. Your suggestion to use the coding that leads to a more rare outcome also makes sense.

They aren't really using a Poisson model, they're really using a log-binomial model with an estimator that isn't the MLE (for increased robustness)
